# Flink client blocks at printing stack trace

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have a flink job which would cause exception because there are some gramma errors in the sql.

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.SqlParserException: SQL parse failed. Encountered "timestamp" at line 1, column 332.
Was expecting one of:
    ")" ...
    "," ...
    
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.calcite.CalciteParser.parse(CalciteParser.java:56) ~[flink-table-blink_2.11-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.ParserImpl.parse(ParserImpl.java:74) ~[flink-table-blink_2.11-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeSql(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:660) ~[flink-table-blink_2.11-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
```

The job was running on detach mode, but the flink client didn't exit when exception happened and blocked at printing stack trace. Here is the "jstack" output of the flink client process, and I can't figure out why it blocked at printing stack trace.

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007ffa7800a800 nid=0x41f1c runnable [0x00007ffa81299000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        - locked <0x00000006c00b26d0> (a java.io.BufferedOutputStream)
        at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:482)
        - locked <0x00000006c00b26b0> (a java.io.PrintStream)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:104)
        - locked <0x00000006c00b27f0> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:185)
        at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:527)
        - locked <0x00000006c00b26b0> (a java.io.PrintStream)
        at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
        at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:823)
        - locked <0x00000006c00b26b0> (a java.io.PrintStream)
        at java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream.println(Throwable.java:748)
        at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Throwable.java:697)
        at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Throwable.java:709)
        at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Throwable.java:709)
        at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Throwable.java:709)
        at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:667)
        - locked <0x00000006c00b26b0> (a java.io.PrintStream)
        at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:643)
        at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:634)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.handleError(CliFrontend.java:945)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1113)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1139)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend$$Lambda$69/2090991873.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.HadoopSecurityContext$$Lambda$70/75470648.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1692)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1139)
```

Comment: Are you sure your job finished? For me, it looks like the client is just waiting for the job to finish. You can check the logs of the job manager for more information or try to access the Web UI. Note that Flink usually restarts parts of the application when an exception occurs.

Comment: @Arvid Heise Thanks for your reply. There are some gramma errors in the sql of that job. The exception is  `org.apache.flink.table.api.SqlParserException` and was throwed from `org.apache.flink.table.planner.calcite.CalciteParser.parse(CalciteParser.java:56)`. So I think the client did not submit the job. This flink job was running on detached mode, so I think it should exit when exception happens. Actually, it blocked and did not exit.